# open-source LAMP package for simple accouting and receiving?

Tags: lamp, accounting

I am involved with a computer-based charity where we take donation of old equipment, often recycle it, mostly rehabilitate it and make it available through grants and 'adoptions', and sell some items.

What we're looking for is a LAMP package that can handle our records of donations of equipment, print receipts for donators, and also track our thrift store sales with receipts. Donators will want receipts of their donations for tax deduction purposes. We'll want to print reports of incoming items from time to time, say monthly and yearly. For the thrift store, we'll also need receipts for that, reports of cash, especially for reconciling cash drops, and also reports of items sold from time to time.

I'm thinking this might be a single package, but it might be two.

We don't want to track our shop inventory with either of these programs -- that's another program/project. We just need to know what was donated and what was sold.

It must be open source, and ideally we'd like it to run on LAMP -- Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP, but  we will consider other open-source platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my last answer I have also looked at [openERP](http://www.openerp.com/) which has modules for absolutely everything.
See the [features page](http://www.openerp.com/discover/features.html)

It is not LAMP but is very easy to install and is in the repositories if you are running Ubuntu.
There is a web interface and a really nice GTK desktop client too which has exactly the same functionality as the web interface but feels more robust.

Might be worth a look if you haven't already found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not yet allowed to vote up answers..

But SQL Ledger is a good free choice.
Build up your favority PostGRE SQL lamp server and go...

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of this type of application but [webERP](http://www.weberp.org/HomePage) or [NOLA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nola/) may be possible solutions.

If these are not suitable post back the reasons why and the missing features to enable better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [SQL Ledger](http://www.sql-ledger.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This is what found on

http://www.bambooinvoice.org/

BambooIncoice is a free opensource invoicing software to help you manage your clients and invoices. It was built by designer and programmer Derek Allard on the great CodeIgniter framework and is a mix of PHP, Javascript and AJAX.

The main features are

- Add new client and edit their
  personal information
- Create new invoice.
- Send invoice to your client by email.
- Create a PDF copy.
- Print invoice.
- Keep track of overdue invoices.
- Export your invoice data to Excel or
  XML.
- Currently available in English,
  French, German, Dutch, Romanian,
  Spanish, Portuguese and  Bulgarian…
  and more languages coming soon.
- Released under the GPL.

you can also consider 
hxxp://www.siwapp.org/
An open source web application meant to help manage & create invoices in a simple, straightforward way. Which is still in alpha stage

Answer (score 0):

If you'll be working with an accounting professional, I'd highly advise discussing this briefly with them to make sure they're willing to work with the data coming out of the tool.

I used to work as a consultant in a company with an accounting consulting division, and their recommendation for this type of question was to go with one of the mainstream packages like QuickBooks (hated: yes.  works: yes.) or peachtree etc...  For slightly bigger shops, it's then something like Microsoft GP or some other competing product. The space isn't that big though.

Bottom line, it's most likely going to be cheaper and easier for you to install a tool with critical mass that accountants and regular users know how to work with, and I haven't seen an open source product that fits that space yet.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.openbravo.com/